# Help: Question about sending emails in Java and reacting to bounced emails 

Tags: jakarta-mail

I need to send email notifications in my Java web application.  I'm using Apache Commons Email and the email goes to the SMTP server and gets delivered fine.

My problem is, I need a few other features, before I build all the functionality myself, I'm wondering if something already exists.  For example:

- the web app needs to drop the email in a "queue" and then return back to the user immediately, rather than waiting around for the send to occur (I'm planning on building a database table with a status field to do this instead of a JMS queue solution).
- if the email bounces or cannot be delivered for some reason after a configured number of send attempts, I need to notify the system administrator (and maybe the user) of the problem; so I guess that means my app has to poll an email inbox for a configured bounce back address.

My question is, I know about JavaMail, but is there a Java framework somewhere that can give me more functionality like queuing the sends, and responding to bounced emails, and so on?

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Rob

PS. The correct answer to my question just might be, "that doesn't exist, you have to build it yourself", if so just let me know. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be "build it yourself".